# jquery append and run tag <script> VS js vanilla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I am updating my application and I have decided to use bootstrap 5 which no longer has the jquery dependency and to eliminate this dependence from my application as well.

So I'm rewriting the javscript part from jquery to js vanilla.

I use AJAX a lot to load content in different divs and for their subsequent manipulation based on certain events triggered by the user.
Unfortunately, in some cases I find myself forced to hang a script tag together with the html part to run a javascript function that I cannot execute in any other way.

For example:

```
<script>myFuncrion(val1, val2, val3);</script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>Other html code ..</div>
</div>
```

With jquery something like this was enough to append the markup to a given div and execute the javascipt function

```
$('#elementToAppend').append(html);
```

Converting this to vanilla js I get something like this

```
document.getElementById('elementToAppend').innerHTML = html;
```

Everything is correctly appended, but obviously the js is not executed

I don't know jquery behind the scenes, but I assume it is being manipulated in some way for the javascript part to run.

I then created a function that would get everything back to working

```
const functionOne = (elem) => {
  // I make the AJAX call...
  let jsAndData = getJsAndData(data);
  
  // Append the html string
  document.querySelector(elem).innerHTML = jsAndData.cleanData;
  // I run the js
  eval(jsAndData.js);
}

const getJsAndData = data => {
  var js = "";

  // Check if there is a <script> tag
  let script = data.match(/<script>(.*?)<\/script>/g);

  // If there is a script tag I extrapolate the js content
  if (script) {
    script.map(val => {
      js = val.replace(/<\/?script>/g, "");
    });

    // I remove the <script> tag and its content from the html string
    let cleanData = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>.*<\/script>/gm, "");

    return { cleanData: cleanData, js: js };
  } else {
    return { cleanData: data, js: js };
  }
};
```

In this way I get the same result I had with jquery, even better, because on the DOM there is no longer any trace of the script tag

Now, my questions are:

1. Am I doing things right?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. Am I completely out of the way?

Comment: You should really not try to parse your HTML with string manipulation functions. Use the DOM instead!

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score -1):

Your way is a correct way. For security reasons (XSS) the script tag is not run when using innerHTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations

Alternative: In MDN you can find hacky code like this to work around from the backend without touching the frontend. I would not recommend this way.

```
const name = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>";
el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the code you put as example can run anywhere regardless of my code, I know the vulnerabilities of innerHTML, but I believe if the content I graft is from me and not entered by the user there should be no problem, also because I do not know what else to use, setHTML () is not supported by almost any browser, insertAdjacentHTML () I do not think it is much due to innerHTML